# Tab-completion for AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using the Bootstrap's Typeahead to display matches as the user types.  I would like to add terminal-like tab-completion.

Perhaps I should have a function like this?

```
function tabcomplete(allPossibleCommandsArray, userTypedString){
//.....
return tabcompletedArray;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? What was your response? Any error messages? Please be specific in your question so you can get specific answers.

Comment: I wanted to check if there is an existing implementation somewhere, so that I don't reinvent the wheel.